# how can we insert multiple values in same query

Tags: php, mysql

I have many records in my table 
I want to know that how can i use loop to insert all record in a single query.
e.g

**DATABASE TABLE**:

invoice_id_**__ Product_1___**_Price_1_***_***_Product_2_**___Price_2_*_*__**_Product_3_*_*__Price_3

similarly there are 10 products i want to insert them against same invoice id(primary key.)
how can I do this please help. thanks

Comment: Could you show us what you've already done?

Comment: Your database schema is not clear and also you can not have multiple record with one `primary key`. What I understand from you question is more like you are looking for schema less - nosql solution. please revise your question.

Comment: @Boynux .. or just a *properly normalized* schema. "NoSQL" is good at some things, but it isn't an immediate substitute for a good (RA) schema design.

Comment: @user2864740, yes, NoSQL is not an immediate substitution for RDBMS and vise-versa, That's why I said "From what I understand" means conditional, right? But sill the question is not clear what he wants to achieve either RDBMS or other solutions. 
Beside that NoSQL is just a tool like the other tools, I really don't understand why some people are so sensitive to this word, and when they see it immediately say that it's not substitution! it's just a tool, and it's good to know there is such a tool, isn't it?

Comment: I'm "sensitive" to suggesting ["NoSQL"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) because it was used as an entirely inappropriate suggestion in context; there is no issue with RA or "schema full" designs here. Also, saying ["NoSQL"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) without qualification - or implying that it is somehow free of schema design requirements - is wild handwaving. If there is a specific [*type*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Examples) of "NoSQL" that may be a suitable then it should be mentioned directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the database design. It's *broken* because it's [not normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). This makes it hard (to the point of being practically unfeasible) to write inserts, query, or establish [DRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_Referential_Integrity).

Instead the tables should look something like the following. Note that the InvoicedProducts table establishes a [Many-to-Many relationship](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php).

```
Invoices
--
invoiceNumber
invoiceDate

Products
--
productName
productPrice          -- current product price

InvoicedProducts
--
Invoice (FK)          -- the Invoice and Product FKs create a compound PK
Product (FK)
invoicedProductPrice  -- product purchased at price (in case the price changes)
```

Then you simply insert the into the `InvoicedProducts` like ..

```
INSERT INTO InvoiceProducts (invoiceId, productId, invoidedProductPrice)
VALUES(.., .., ..)
```

.. the appropriate number of times (or, once per Invoice/Product pair). Use separate INSERT statements, but a *single* transaction.

Comment: i want that invoice id must be for new transaction..

Comment: I want that invoice id must unique be for new transaction.. take the example of any products selling system. Customer buy many products and every product has its own price,quantity,and weight.When we receive bill we see that there are many products that customer buy along with their prices but  invoice ID is unique for every transaction or bill. I just want to make simple products selling system like in departmental stores.

Comment: @Mohsin That's fine. Insert *one* Invoice record. It sound like, in your case, this will have an invoiceId column as the PK. Then, use that *same* invoiceId for inserting *all* (1,2,..100,etc) related InvoicedProducts records. I've added a link to the "Many-to-Many" text in the post which you may find useful. In the link, Order ~ Invoice, and OrderLine ~ InvoicedProduct.

Answer (score 2):

From the mySQL Manual

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Here is the documentation link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$con=mysqli_connect(hostname,username,password,databasename);

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table_name (a,b,c)
    VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin'),('absss','avdss','advas'),(7,8,9)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is similar as below

-- INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(COLUMN1, COLUMN2) VALUES(VALUE1,VALUE2),(VALUE3,VALUE4)....

But if you have multiple places to insert/update/delete, check the database design. You may need to normalize it.